# Why is this Python dict comprehension taking forever to run?

Tags: python

function `pair_exists()` takes two items as input:

- `nums`: a list (or other data structure)
- `target`: an integer

The function should return `True` if any two numbers within `nums` sum up to target. The list that I'm having it run on is 10,000 entries from between 1 & a million. It's taking 20+ mins to run (though I do have a MacBook Air so it's not the most high powered), so I'm assuming it's broken and/or computationally wasteful. How do I get this to run?

```
import itertools 

random.seed(a=13, version=2)
random_numbers = random.sample(range(1, 1000000), 10000)

def pair_exists(nums: list, target: int):
    result = [seq for i in range(len(nums), 0, -1) for seq in itertools.combinations(nums, i) if sum(seq) == target]

print(pair_exists(random_numbers, 38109)) # SHOULD RETURN TRUE
print(pair_exists(random_numbers, 13538)) # SHOULD RETURN FALSE
```

Comment: I don't see a dictionary comprehension here.

Comment: If the question is about finding pairs, why are you checking combinations of every possible length? Also, would you rather have help working out the fast solution (faster than after fixing the combinations thing), or just get told the fast solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you are checking for subsets of any size. Your problem statement says that you are interested only in pairs.

Taking your style of approach, we could write up a solution in `O(n^2)`:

```
def pair_exists(nums, target):
  return any(sum(subset) == target for subset in itertools.combinations(nums, 2))
```

But this is still slow on large arrays. Instead, we could try to use two iterators, which would perform in `O(n)` (I guess in `O(n*log(n))` because of the sort).

```
def pair_exists(nums, target):
  nums = sorted(nums)
  start = 0
  end = len(nums) - 1
  while start < end:
    if nums[start] + nums[end] < target:
      start += 1
    elif nums[start] + nums[end] > target:
      end -= 1
    else:
      return True
  return False
```

Answer (score 1):

This is O(lots) and doesn’t do what it says in the name; it looks for any size of subset with the correct sum:

```py
def pair_exists(nums: list, target: int):
    result = [seq for i in range(len(nums), 0, -1) for seq in itertools.combinations(nums, i) if sum(seq) == target]
```

(Also, it doesn’t return anything.)

---

This is O(n²), your original but adapted to be correct:

```py
def pair_exists(nums: list, target: int):
    return any(sum(pair) == target for pair in itertools.combinations(nums, 2))
```

---

@Bill Lynch posted an O(n log n) answer with sorting.

---

This is an O(n) solution by figuring out what would make a correct pair with each value, and checking if it appears earlier:

```py
from typing import Iterable


def pair_exists(nums: Iterable[int], target: int):
    seen = set()

    for num in nums:
        if (target - num) in seen:
            return True

        seen.add(num)

    return False
```

The set is a collection with O(1) insertion and membership testing, allowing the “appears earlier” check to be fast.

Answer (score 0):

this function not efficient and not related to the machine you're using.

try something like that to check if you have pairs that sum the target

```
def pair_exists(nums: list, target: int):
    for num in nums:
        if target - num in nums:
            return True
    return False
```